# Android GreenDao

Tags: android, greendao

I made a new db, the entities are present in the following schema:

```
    Entity image =schema.addEntity("Image");
    image.setTableName("Images");
    image.addStringProperty("id").primaryKey();
    image.addStringProperty("url");


    Entity community = schema.addEntity("Community");
    community.setTableName("Communities");
    community.addStringProperty("id").primaryKey();
    community.addStringProperty("title");
    community.addStringProperty("imageId");


    Entity user=schema.addEntity("User");
    user.setTableName("Users");
    user.addStringProperty("id").primaryKey();
    user.addStringProperty("fullName");
    user.addStringProperty("imageId");

    Entity relation=schema.addEntity("Relation");
    relation.addStringProperty("userId");
    relation.addStringProperty("communityId");
```

Is possible in GreenDao to return the whole object Image related, instead of just ImageId ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insetad of setting the ImageId as a string you have to build a relation with .addToOne like this:

```
Property imageIdProperty = user.addLongProperty("imageId").getProperty();
user.addToOne(image, imageIdProperty);
```

with user.getPicture() you should be able   to get the picture as an Picture Object instead of the id.

EDIT: If a user should have multiple images, use a ToMany relation. You can see how it's done in the greendao docs http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/relations/

For you Relations try using a ToMany Relation like this:

```
Property communityId = user.addLongProperty("communityId").getProperty();
ToMany communityToUsers = community.addToMany(user, communityId);
```

with community.getUsers() you should get all users in that community

Comment: Thank you for the image, can you tell me please also if the table with relations is ok or i need to implement ToMany also for user and community, because user can be in many communities and a community can contain many users ?

Comment: i added a solution for your user-community relation

Comment: Thank you very much